# AWS SNS Sandbox mode: No quota left for account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm getting  `No quota left for account error` in Amazon SNS SMS sandbox mode. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the quota is a limitation of being in Sandbox mode.

See: [Introducing the SMS sandbox for Amazon SNS | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-sms-sandbox-for-amazon-sns/)

If you wish to go beyond the sandbox limits, you should exit the sandbox mode by submitting a request to AWS Support.